# Snap SVG - Check if one transformed rectangle is completely inside of another?

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I'm using Snap SVG to manipulate SVGs within a web app that I'm making. In this web app I have two rectangles that start out with one being inside of the other, call them rectInner and rectOuter. The aim is to allow the user to transform rectOuter (scale, rotate, translate) such that rectInner is always *strictly* inside of rectOuter. To be clear, rectInner will never move or be transformed.

My approach to this problem is to get the bounding box of both rectInner and rectOuter, and check to see if the first is strictly contained within the second. Snap SVG provides a function isBBoxIntersect(rectInner, rectOuter), but it only tells me if parts of the bounding boxes intersect, not if one is contained within the other.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

It seems now that I somewhat misunderstood the concept of bounding boxes, but the problem should be simpler. If I can find a way of calculating the four vertices of rectOuter after all of the transformations, then so long as the corners of rectInner are inside the of the path constructed from those vertices, the entire rectangle is. I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
##### coffeescript
el = Snap('rect#outer')
mat = el.attr('transform').totalMatrix

left = +el.attr('x')
top = +el.attr('y')
right = left + (+el.attr('width'))
bottom = top + (+el.attr('height'))

console.log(left, top, right, bottom)

points =  {
    x: mat.x(left, top)
    y: mat.y(left, top)
    x2:mat.x(right, top)
    y2:mat.y(right, top)
    x3:mat.x(right, bottom)
    y3:mat.y(right, bottom )
    x4:mat.x(left, bottom)
    y4:mat.y(left, bottom)
}
```

use matrix!
you can find more matrix in `mat` variable. 
if totalMatrix didn't work then try another.